# OpenSSL : Encrypt with private key and decrypt with public key in RSA

Tags: encryption, rsa, digital-signature, signature

I want to encrypt a file with the private key using OpenSSL with the RSA algorithm:

```
openssl rsautl -in txt.txt -out txt2.txt -inkey private.pem -encrypt
```

Now if I do a decrypt operation:

```
openssl rsautl -in txt2.txt -pubin -inkey public.pem -decrypt
```

> A private key is needed for this operation

I know that I should use the public key to encrypt, and if I use the private key, I get a signature.

However, I want to do that for studying purposes.

Comment: My guess is that in the first command, even though you have passed a private key it is only reading the first two components of the file as the public key and is performing a public key operation. You must use the sign and verify subcommands to do what you appear to be trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

You are using keys wrongly. In public-key cryptography, *encryption* uses a public key:

```
openssl rsautl -in txt.txt -out txt2.txt -inkey public.pem -pubin -encrypt
```

And for decryption, the private key related to the public key is used:

```
openssl rsautl -in txt2.txt -inkey private.pem -decrypt
```

The private key (*without* `-pubin`) can be used for encryption since it actually contains the public exponent. Note that RSA should not normally be used to encrypt data directly, but only to 'encapsulate' (RSA-KEM) or 'wrap' the key(s) used for symmetric encryption.

But you mention you actually want to study signature. Although historically RSA signature was sometimes described as 'encrypting with the private key', that description is misleading and actually implementing that was found to be insecure. Sign and verify are actually different operations separate from encryption and decryption, and `rsautl` performs only *part* of them. For example, you *can* do:

```
# hash the data and encode the result in ASN.1 
openssl rsautl -sign -in hashenc.dat -out sig.dat -inkey private.pem
...
# on the recipient (with signature and purportedly correct data)
openssl rsautl -verify -in sig.dat -out hashenc.dat -inkey public.pem -pubin 
# or often more appropriate use a certificate for the public key
openssl rsautl -verify -in sig.dat -out hashenc.dat -inkey cert.pem -certin
# now either decode hashenc.dat and compare the hash
# to a new hash of the data (which should be the same)
# or compare all of hashenc.dat to an encoding of a new hash
```

Instead it is better to use `openssl dgst` which performs the entire signature and verification *sequence* as specified by PKCS1 [e.g. rfc8017](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017). For example for RSASSA-PKCS1v1_5 signature *with SHA256*:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private.pem -in data.txt -out sig.dat
# or can be abbreviated
openssl sha256 -sign private.pem -in data.txt -out sig.dat
# hashes the data, encodes the hash, does type 1 padding and modexp d
...
openssl dgst -sha256 -verify public.pem -in data.txt -signature     sig.dat
# or abbreviated 
openssl sha256 -verify public.pem -in data.txt -signature sig.dat 
# does modexp e and type 1 unpadding, and compares the result to a hash of the data

# notice you don't specify which key is public or private
# because this command knows what to expect

# however it does not accept the public key from a certificate, 
# you must extract the public key from the cert first
```

This form (but not `rsautl`) also supports the newer and technically better, but not as widely used, PSS padding. This is only referenced on the `dgst` man page, and mostly documented on the `pkeyutl` man page, which isn't totally obvious.

On other Stacks where this is more on-topic, see e.g.:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/93603/understanding-digitial-certifications
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/87325/if-the-public-key-cant-be-used-for-decrypting
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11879/is-encrypting-data-with-a-private-key-dangerous
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68822/trying-to-understand-rsa-and-its-terminology
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2123/rsa-encryption-with-private-key-and-decryption-with-a-public-key
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15997/is-rsa-encryption-the-same-as-signature-generation
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/15295/why-the-need-to-hash-before-signing-small-data

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks for the edits. Do you want to make this answer as community?

Comment: I don't see any reason to; in my opinion it is now complete as well as correct, and there's no need to encourage further change. Of course as always on Stack anyone (else) who wants further change can propose or request it.

Comment: but why is it that you cant decrypt what was encrypted using the privateKey, isn't it the same since the private key is the inverse of the public key?

Comment: @ezio you are reading wrongly. The OP tries to decrypt with the public key. The private key contains all information for the owner to encrypt and then decrypt the messages encrypted with that public key.

Answer (score -1):

I see that you "want to do that for studying purposes." Then, for anyone else looking at this answer, it shall too be used for "studying purposes," and not for any production or purportedly secure system.

As @kelalaka points out, in public-key cryptography, the public key is used for encryption, and the private key is used for decryption. However, if you are studying RSA, you also know that "encryption/decryption" and "signature/verification" use the same underlying mathematical formula:
[image]

Further, [encryption raises `m` to the power of `e`, mod(`n`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Encryption) and [decryption raises `c` to the power of `d`, mod(`n`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Decryption), where `(e, n)` are the public key and `(d, n)` are the private key. Given the mathematical basis, I think a natural question becomes, how can we raise `m` to the power of `d` instead, and vice versa?

It turns out that [message signing raises `hash(m)` to the power of `d`, mod(`n`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Signing_messages), and [message verification raises `tag` to the power of `e`, mod(`n`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)#Signing_messages). If you loosely define "encrypt" as "raise `m` to the power of a number, mod (`n`)", then Openssl CLI can *"encrypt a file with the private key"* (actually, sign to create a `tag`). The `rsautl` subcommand can be used like so (Note that the input data must be of the same bit-length as the key used for encrypting/signing, hence the 501 bytes of 'A' padding):

```
# Create the file to have a `tag` created for:
python3 -c "print('Hello World'+501*'A', end='')" > txt.txt
# Create a `tag` called `txt2.txt` for the `txt.txt` file:
openssl pkeyutl -sign -inkey private_key.pem -in tx.txt -out txt2.txt -pkeyopt rsa_padding_mode:none
```

Now `txt2.txt` contains the result of raising `txt.txt` to the power of `d`, mod(`n`).

If you loosely define "decrypt" as "raise `m` to the power of a number, mod (`n`)", then Openssl CLI can *"decrypt a file with the public key"* (actually, verify but see the raw results of an intermediate step). The `rsautl` subcommand can be used like so:

```
openssl rsautl -verify -inkey public_key.pem -pubin -in txt2.txt -raw -hexdump
```

Now `stdout` contains the result of raising `txt2.txt` to the power of `e`, mod(`n`).

Comment: You are advising the wrong way.  A private key must never be used to encrypt!

Comment: [Encrypting with private key in Public Key InfraStructure](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5459/18298)